# apexcharts horizontal bar chart spanning all x-axis and changing color based on time/date

Tags: apexcharts

I am looking on a way to get this done in Apexcharts:

I want a horizontal bar chart where the x-axis is a time-line and the y-axis is a player like (lamp)

so if lamp is turned on at a specific date/time i want a vertical line and from that point the bar should change color to green and when i have an off i also want a vertical line and from that moment the bar should turn red

what is the best way to get this done in apexcharts? because i am looking at options but can't find a way to get this done.

Here is a sample of the data after i extracted and manipulated it:

```
{x: "2024 Feb 04 19:45:35 UTC", y: On},
{x: "2024 Feb 04 19:45:35 UTC", y: On},
{x: "2024 Feb 04 20:55:32 UTC", y: Off},
{x: "2024 Feb 04 20:55:32 UTC", y: Off},
{x: "2024 Feb 05 05:44:22 UTC", y: On},
{x: "2024 Feb 05 05:44:22 UTC", y: On},
{x: "2024 Feb 05 06:06:51 UTC", y: Off},
{x: "2024 Feb 05 06:06:51 UTC", y: Off},
```

But this is manipulated like i did my other charts, but i normally base my manipulation on how the data should look in the chart code

Comment: share sample data also the code you tried and where you are facing issues!

Comment: I added a sample of the data, but normally i manipulate my data based on the chart and how the data should look like, not the other way around